# How to draw the walking dotted circle path using GMSMapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-maps, gmsmapview

The latest iOS Google Map App has dotted circle paths when a user searches for walking directions.

How can I achieve the same effect(dotted circle path) using GMSMapView in iOS?

Any suggestions or comments or opinions would be greatly appreciated.
thanks

[image]

Comment: have you find any solution for this, i have same requirement. Please let me know

Comment: Hello Friend do you get any solution please add i have same requirement.